# hits and misses are increasing together in memcached which is located in Doctrine of Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, memcached

everyone.I want to use Memcached to cache the results returned by Doctrine.I have configured it.Now the data can be cached,but when I reflesh the page,I found what was described in the title.I want to monitor what that Doctrine want to get.But It seems that there isn't `monitor` command which is in Redis.Now I don't know what I should to do.
The following is my configuration:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    ...
    memcached.servers:
            - { host: 127.0.0.1, port: 11211 }

# app/config/config.yml
services:
    memcached:
        class: Memcached
        calls:
            - [ addServers, [ %memcached.servers% ]]

    doctrine.cache.memcached:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache
        calls:
            - [setMemcached, ['@memcached']]

#app/config/config_prod.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestMemcachedController extends Controller{
    /**
     * @Route("/memcached")
     */
    public function testAction(){
        $memcached = new \Memcached();
        $memcached->addServer('localhost',11211);
        $cacheDriver = new MemcachedCache();
        $cacheDriver->setMemcached($memcached);

        $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('select image from AppBundle:ProductImage image')
            ->setResultCacheDriver($cacheDriver)
            ->useResultCache(true)
            ->getResult();

        return new Response("<html>
                <head>
                    <title>test</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    hello
                </body>
            </html>");
    }
}
```

And `ProductImage` entity has a foreign key which refer to `Product` entitiy.I think this point is not matter.
Other configuration is default configuration.

Any suggestion is helpful.